# docker consul service discovery

Tags: docker, nginx, consul

I am working on SOA system and i am using consul service discovery with nginx and registrator. everything is dockerized. the idea is to have all this backend services running inside a docker container to be visible to the consul server and use nginx as a load balancer to route requests to the correct service.

I've set up consul and registrator successfully and tested it using the consul UI. If I spin up a service running inside docker (redis for example), I can see consul discovers the service. The problem i am having is configuring nginx to connect to the upstream servers. I have a bunch of PHP services running inside a container and I want nginx to connect to the correct upstream server and serve the response. however nginx always returns a 502.

here is my nginx.conf file

```
upstream app-cluster {
   least_conn;
   {{range service "app-http"}}server {{.Address}}:{{.Port}} 
    max_fails=3 fail_timeout=60 weight=1;
    {{else}}server 127.0.0.1:65535; # force a 502{{end}}
 }

 server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app-cluster;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host \$host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
}
```

}

nginx error log :

2018/08/29 09:56:29 [error] 27#27: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.10.24, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:32795/", host: "aci-host-01:8080"

does anyone know any comprehensive guide on this or might have an idea where the problem might be? 
thanks in advance

Comment: If services are being registered in Consul with 127.0.0.1 as their IP address, nothing will be able to reach them from anywhere else.  That would be consistent with your log message.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, you're right. I checked the consul UI and stragenly none of my services have ip address assigned to them. (eg. :9000). which i assume then it just fills in localhost. i.e 127.0.0.1:9000

As far as i understand, the registrator is supposed to monitor new containers  and register them as they're up and running. my services are all running inside a a container. do you know a possbile cause for this issue.
thanks